# Search if element does not have class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked through a bunch of posts and haven't found a solution that seems to work... getting kinda frustrated at this point, so I figured I'd see if someone else had a solution.

So, I'm trying to validate a field with the attribute "required" on a widget I'm creating, the problem being that when the user clicks the "create" button, it creates a new visible section and also duplicates it in a hidden section with the class "hide" for various reasons.

My validation code looks like this:

```
var $required = $("input[required]").css('border', '1px solid #CCC');
    $invalid = $required.filter(function(){
        return !this.value;
    }).css('border', '1px solid red');

if($invalid.length){
    alert('Please fill in all required fields');
} else {
    //ajax call
}
```

This works just fine on all my other widgets, but since there is a hidden duplicate in this new widget, it passes on the visible fields but fails on the hidden fields.

My solution was to add a second part to "if" statement to search for whether invalid has a length AND if its parent element ***doesn't*** have the class "hide". However, changing the statement to the following doesn't seem to work:

```
if( $invalid.length && !$("input[required]").closest("li").hasClass("hide") ){
    alert('Please fill in all required fields');
} else {
    //ajax call
}
```

It seems to pass every time now...

The (general) structure of the element I'm trying to validate is - I removed most of the code, just to simplify it for viewing:

```
<li>
    <div class="row-fluid>
        <div class="span3">
            <!-- Some content -->
        </div>
        <div class="span9">
            <input type="text" required />
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
</li>
```

The hidden element follows the same structure, just it has

```
<li class="hide">
```

as the parent element, instead.

*I assume there's something wrong in the syntax of my jQuery, but I've been trying to fix this issue for so long now that I'm probably just overlooking something super simple...*

Thoughts? ;)

Answer (score 3):

Your `if` statement is testing whether **none** of the required elements is in a hidden `LI`, since `hasClass("hide")` is true if any of the selected elements has the class.

You can use the `:visible` pseudo-class in your selector so you only test the unhidden elements.

```
var $required = $("input[required]:visible").css('border', '1px solid #CCC');
```

or you can use search from the unhidden parents to find the required inputs.

```
var $required = $("li:not(.hide) input[required]").css('border', '1px solid #CCC');
```

or you can do the check in your filter function:

```
$invalid = $required.filter(function() {
    return !this.value && !$(this).closest("li").hasClass("hide");
});
```

Comment: Wow, I knew I was overcomplicating this. The :visible selector works perfectly! Thank you so much for saving me from going insane on this :P